# Getting LinkedIn Profile Picture

Tags: linkedin-api, profile-picture

Is there an easy way to grab a users LinkedIn profile photo?

Ideally similar to how you would with Facebook - http://graph.facebook.com/userid/picture

Comment: Make note of [ccoloma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53886138/1747491) below, as this has changed **a lot** with `v2` of the API. The accepted and top-voted answers are for `v1`, which will be deprecated soon.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Not as easy... You need to go through OAuth, then on behalf of the member, you ask for:

`http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/{user-id}/picture-url`

Comment: That's a shame, had hoped there was an easier mechanism.

Comment: so we do need to do two calls, the first one to get the picture url, and the second one to get the actual picture?

Comment: saintmac. No if you only want hte picture just call this url. the {user-id} is a variable and "picture-url" is actual text you put in the url to get the picture. However in my testing this returns the smaller picture not the original. I recommend the answer below using picture-urls::(original)

Comment: it is not displaying the image.i might b doing something wrong.any help?

Comment: Is there way with having to auth?

Comment: works for me in 2016, you probably need https instead of http and an Authorization header, using a Bearer access_token, so in your http headers put "Authorization" : "Bearer <access_token>"

Comment: In my case, I needed to enable HTTPS. I was getting the "need SSL" error.

Answer (score 52):

You can retrieve the original photo size with this call:

[http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/picture-urls::(original)](http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/picture-urls%3a%3a%28original%29)

Note that this could be any size, so you'll need to do scaling on your side, but the image is the original one uploaded by the user.

Comment: Can you explain this in a more easy way please.

Comment: a tiny point to make - the image is 'the original one uploaded by the user'... with the addition of a linkedIn logo in the corner :)

Comment: How to get thumb image of linkedin Profile picture?

Comment: @Nikkie Use `picture-url` instead of `picture-urls::(original)`

Comment: @Tabloo Quijico Unfortunately Linkedin logo in the corner on original image too exists =)

Comment: It looks like LinkedIn disabled retrieving the large picture altogether now since I'm getting an empty <pictureurls /> tag in response to this request and a mere 100x100 picture for regular profile API calls.

Comment: Why not check the `naturalWidth` & `naturalHeight` of the image?

Answer (score 20):

If you use the 2.0 version of the API (all developers need to migrate [by March 1, 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq?context=linkedin/consumer/context?trk=eml_mktg_gco_dev_api_comms)), you should use projections to expand the `profilePicture.displayImage`. If you do this, you will have a full JSON element `displayImage~` (the '~' is not a typo) inside `profilePicture` with all the info you may need.

`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))`

You can see more at the [Profile Picture API doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/profile-picture) to look at the JSON response or [the Profile API doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api?context=linkedin/consumer/context).

Answer (score 12):

Once the Linkedin **user authentication** using OAuth 2.x is done, make a request to the people URL.

> https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,email-address,first-name,last-name,formatted-name,picture-url)?format=json

Where `~` stands for current authenticated user. The response will be something like this ...

```
{
  "id": "KPxRFxLxuX",
  "emailAddress": "johndoe@example.com",
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "formattedName": "John Doe",
  "pictureUrl": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_0QblxThAqcTCt8rrncxxO5JAr...cjSsn6gRQ2b"
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: how do you get the pic in a slightly bigger size though? The one I'm getting is super small :/

Comment: @dietbacon have you already found a solution for you problem?

Comment: @VitorOliveira no :(

Comment: This is the official method to get the users details, but as @dietbacon said, the resolution is very tiny and its very low quality too

Answer (score 6):

I'm using OWIN in my solution so after the user allows your application to use LinkedIn credentials a simple and plain GET request to URL https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(picture-URL)?format=json, as explained before with a Bearer authorization in request headers, solved my problems.

My Startup.Auth.cs file

```
var linkedInOptions = new LinkedInAuthenticationOptions()
{
   ClientId = [ClientID],
   ClientSecret = [ClientSecret],
   Provider = new LinkedInAuthenticationProvider()
   {
      OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
      {
          // This is the access token received by your application after user allows use LinkedIn credentials
          context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(
              "urn:linkedin:accesstoken", context.AccessToken));
          context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(
              "urn:linkedin:name", context.Name));
          context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(
              "urn:linkedin:username", context.UserName));
          context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(
              "urn:linkedin:email", context.Email));
          context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(
              "urn:linkedin:id", context.Id));

          return Task.FromResult(0);
      }
   }
};

app.UseLinkedInAuthentication(linkedInOptions);
```

My method to get the user's profile picture in LinkedIn:

```
public string GetUserPhotoUrl(string accessToken)
{
   string result = string.Empty;
   var apiRequestUri = new Uri("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(picture-url)?format=json");
   using (var webClient = new WebClient())
   {
      webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + accessToken);
      var json = webClient.DownloadString(apiRequestUri);
      dynamic x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
      string userPicture = x.pictureUrl;
      result = userPicture;
   }
   return result;
}
```

And finally a snippet of my action that consumes the method above:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
{
   ...
   var externalIdentity = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalIdentityAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
   string accessToken =
               externalIdentity.Result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "urn:linkedin:accesstoken").Value;
   model.PhotoUrl = GetUserPhotoUrl(accessToken);
   ...
}
```

I hope it could help.
Best regards

Answer (score 4):

This works well for me!

*Explained -*

**This is for a thumbnail with all other data-**

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,location,picture-urls::(original),specialties,public-profile-url,email-address,formatted-name)?format=json
```

**This is for original image with all other data -**

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,location,picture-url,specialties,public-profile-url,email-address,formatted-name)?format=json
```

Just use `picture-urls::(original)`instead of `picture-url` !

This is currently being used in [Gradbee](http://gradbee.com)

Comment: getting formatted-name (null) (null) with url  for original image with all other data - any idea?

Comment: @KrutikaSonawala there might be some problem with the linkedin account that you are authorizing. 
check this link with your own linkedin profile
`https://apigee.com/console/linkedin`

Answer (score 2):

When you login to linkedin, you will get accesstoken. Use that access token and you can retrieve users data

```
 LinkedInApiClient client = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);
                        com.google.code.linkedinapi.schema.Person person = client.getProfileForCurrentUser(EnumSet.of(
                                ProfileField.ID, ProfileField.FIRST_NAME, ProfileField.LAST_NAME, ProfileField.HEADLINE,
                                ProfileField.INDUSTRY, ProfileField.PICTURE_URL, ProfileField.DATE_OF_BIRTH,
                                ProfileField.LOCATION_NAME, ProfileField.MAIN_ADDRESS, ProfileField.LOCATION_COUNTRY));
    String imgageUrl=person.getPictureUrl();
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is simply to display the photo on your site then the LinkedIn [Member Profile Plugin](https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/member-profile) may work out for you.  It will display the photo, some additional info, along with LinkedIn branding.

Since the LinkedIn API is designed to be used only on behalf of the [current logged in user](https://developer.linkedin.com/legal/api-terms-of-use) it does not offer similar functionality as the facebook graph api.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution and it works very very well:

```
def callback(self):
    self.validate_oauth2callback()
    oauth_session = self.service.get_auth_session(
        data={'code': request.args['code'],
              'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
              'redirect_uri': self.get_callback_url()},
        decoder=jsondecoder
    )
    me = oauth_session.get('people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,public-profile-url,email-address,picture-url,picture-urls::(original))?format=json&oauth2_access_token='+str(oauth_session.access_token), data={'x-li-format': 'json'}, bearer_auth=False).json()
    social_id = me['id']
    name = me['firstName']
    surname = me['lastName']
    email = me['emailAddress']
    url = me['publicProfileUrl']
    image_small = me.get('pictureUrl', None)
    image_large = me.get('pictureUrls', {}).get('values', [])[0]
    return social_id, name, surname, email, url, image_small, image_large, me
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this works

```
image= auth.extra.raw_info.pictureUrls.values.last.first
```

with omniauth-linkedin gem

Answer (score 0):

This may not be quite what you're asking for, but it's useful for individual investigations.

Call up the page in Firefox, left-click the menu over the background image.
Select Inspect Element(Q).

search for -target-image"
That will be the end of of id attribute in an img element.
The src attribute of that img element, will be the URL of the background image.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a user profile picture by just doing the below-defined steps.

**Linked URL** [https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people/id=USER_ID?projection=(id,profilePicture(displayImage~digitalmediaAsset:playableStreams))](https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people/id=USER_ID?projection=(id,profilePicture(displayImage%7EdigitalmediaAsset:playableStreams)))

**USER_ID**: yjuMzBoycX // test userID.

Call this API to fetch the profile picture of the provided userId,

You will get the response Look like below, in the response, ProfilePicute -> elements -> identifiers -> identifier
is the link to your user profile picture and will be accessible by just clicking on the link.

**Sample Response**. // test user profile picture.
you will get four pictures with different resolutions in the element array.

```
{
"profilePicture": {
    "displayImage": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C4D03AQEJkSP2gLg1aA",
    "displayImage~": {
        "paging": {
            "count": 10,
            "start": 0,
            "links": []
        },
        "elements": [
            {
                "artifact": "urn:li:digitalmediaMediaArtifact:(urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C4D03AQEJkSP2gLg1aA,urn:li:digitalmediaMediaArtifactClass:profile-displayphoto-shrink_100_100)",
                "authorizationMethod": "PUBLIC",
                "data": {
                    "com.linkedin.digitalmedia.mediaartifact.StillImage": {
                        "orientation": "TopLeft",
                        "storageAspectRatio": {
                            "widthAspect": 1.0,
                            "heightAspect": 1.0,
                            "formatted": "1.00:1.00"
                        },
                        "storageSize": {
                            "width": 100,
                            "height": 100
                        },
                        "rawMetadataTags": [],
                        "scale": "DOWN",
                        "mediaType": "image/jpeg",
                        "rawCodecSpec": {
                            "name": "jpeg",
                            "type": "image"
                        },
                        "displaySize": {
                            "width": 100.0,
                            "uom": "PX",
                            "height": 100.0
                        },
                        "displayAspectRatio": {
                            "widthAspect": 1.0,
                            "heightAspect": 1.0,
                            "formatted": "1.00:1.00"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "identifiers": [
                    {
                        "identifier": "https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C4D03AQEJkSP2gLg1aA/profile-displayphoto-shrink_100_100/0/1661232745172?e=1712188800&v=beta&t=bEUF4w6ndy7kaRDbq1Lyx1bRuZNHDL1FD7H-D6PAafY",
                        "index": 0,
                        "mediaType": "image/jpeg",
                        "file": "urn:li:digitalmediaFile:(urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C4D03AQEJkSP2gLg1aA,urn:li:digitalmediaArtifactClass:profile-displayphoto-shrink_100_100,0)",
                        "identifierType": "EXTERNAL_URL",
                        "identifierExpiresInSeconds": 1712188800
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "artifact": "urn:li:digitalmediaMediaArtifact:(urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C4D03AQEJkSP2gLg1aA,urn:li:digitalmediaMediaArtifactClass:profile-displayphoto-shrink_200_200)",
                "authorizationMethod": "PUBLIC",
                "data": {
                    "com.linkedin.digitalmedia.mediaartifact.StillImage": {
                        "orientation": "TopLeft",
                        "storageAspectRatio": {
                            "widthAspect": 1.0,
                            "heightAspect": 1.0,
                            "formatted": "1.00:1.00"
                        },
                        "storageSize": {
                            "width": 200,
                            "height": 200
                        },
                        "rawMetadataTags": [],
                        "scale": "DOWN",
                        "mediaType": "image/jpeg",
                        "rawCodecSpec": {
                            "name": "jpeg",
                            "type": "image"
                        },
                        "displaySize": {
                            "width": 200.0,
                            "uom": "PX",
                            "height": 200.0
                        },
                        "displayAspectRatio": {
                            "widthAspect": 1.0,
                            "heightAspect": 1.0,
                            "formatted": "1.00:1.00"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "identifiers": [
                    {
                        "identifier": "https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C4D03AQEJkSP2gLg1aA/profile-displayphoto-shrink_200_200/0/1661232745172?e=1712188800&v=beta&t=nDPU4akewODGbgzUJxj4fupr7Xv66YbvLdIC89-WP4k",
                        "index": 0,
                        "mediaType": "image/jpeg",
                        "file": "urn:li:digitalmediaFile:(urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C4D03AQEJkSP2gLg1aA,urn:li:digitalmediaArtifactClass:profile-displayphoto-shrink_200_200,0)",
                        "identifierType": "EXTERNAL_URL",
                        "identifierExpiresInSeconds": 1712188800
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "artifact": "urn:li:digitalmediaMediaArtifact:(urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C4D03AQEJkSP2gLg1aA,urn:li:digitalmediaMediaArtifactClass:profile-displayphoto-shrink_400_400)",
                "authorizationMethod": "PUBLIC",
                "data": {
                    "com.linkedin.digitalmedia.mediaartifact.StillImage": {
                        "orientation": "TopLeft",
                        "storageAspectRatio": {
                            "widthAspect": 1.0,
                            "heightAspect": 1.0,
                            "formatted": "1.00:1.00"
                        },
                        "storageSize": {
                            "width": 400,
                            "height": 400
                        },
                        "rawMetadataTags": [],
                        "scale": "DOWN",
                        "mediaType": "image/jpeg",
                        "rawCodecSpec": {
                            "name": "jpeg",
                            "type": "image"
                        },
                        "displaySize": {
                            "width": 400.0,
                            "uom": "PX",
                            "height": 400.0
                        },
                        "displayAspectRatio": {
                            "widthAspect": 1.0,
                            "heightAspect": 1.0,
                            "formatted": "1.00:1.00"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "identifiers": [
                    {
                        "identifier": "https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C4D03AQEJkSP2gLg1aA/profile-displayphoto-shrink_400_400/0/1661232745172?e=1712188800&v=beta&t=VQDb7KtpR5gT69eTuA8n0xuE_WYOJD5kkPgmXA_a7dM",
                        "index": 0,
                        "mediaType": "image/jpeg",
                        "file": "urn:li:digitalmediaFile:(urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C4D03AQEJkSP2gLg1aA,urn:li:digitalmediaArtifactClass:profile-displayphoto-shrink_400_400,0)",
                        "identifierType": "EXTERNAL_URL",
                        "identifierExpiresInSeconds": 1712188800
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "artifact": "urn:li:digitalmediaMediaArtifact:(urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C4D03AQEJkSP2gLg1aA,urn:li:digitalmediaMediaArtifactClass:profile-displayphoto-shrink_800_800)",
                "authorizationMethod": "PUBLIC",
                "data": {
                    "com.linkedin.digitalmedia.mediaartifact.StillImage": {
                        "orientation": "TopLeft",
                        "storageAspectRatio": {
                            "widthAspect": 1.0,
                            "heightAspect": 1.0,
                            "formatted": "1.00:1.00"
                        },
                        "storageSize": {
                            "width": 800,
                            "height": 800
                        },
                        "rawMetadataTags": [],
                        "scale": "UNCHANGED",
                        "mediaType": "image/jpeg",
                        "rawCodecSpec": {
                            "name": "jpeg",
                            "type": "image"
                        },
                        "displaySize": {
                            "width": 800.0,
                            "uom": "PX",
                            "height": 800.0
                        },
                        "displayAspectRatio": {
                            "widthAspect": 1.0,
                            "heightAspect": 1.0,
                            "formatted": "1.00:1.00"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "identifiers": [
                    {
                        "identifier": "https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C4D03AQEJkSP2gLg1aA/profile-displayphoto-shrink_800_800/0/1661232745172?e=1712188800&v=beta&t=o1MXA1LurNoZwPsrZ_M5Uk65JvLjqo_Ta9LOPbj5dUo",
                        "index": 0,
                        "mediaType": "image/jpeg",
                        "file": "urn:li:digitalmediaFile:(urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C4D03AQEJkSP2gLg1aA,urn:li:digitalmediaArtifactClass:profile-displayphoto-shrink_800_800,0)",
                        "identifierType": "EXTERNAL_URL",
                        "identifierExpiresInSeconds": 1712188800
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
},
"id": "yjuMzBoycX"
```

}