# Get LinkedIn user profile pictures

Tags: linkedin-api

Like facebook http://graph.facebook.com/userid/picture, is there an easy way to get multiple profile pictures in LinkedIn?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/6955647/5389585

Comment: I have explained in another question. that is working fine in my case. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/77926438/19236491](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77926438/19236491)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use oAuth for linkedin, and use url like:
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,public-profile-url,picture-url)

See here: [Linkedin API](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields)

Hope it helps

Comment: `http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/picture-urls::(original)` gets the original, but it still has a LI watermark
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9513804/2586761