# Grab profile picture from LinkedIn to my web site

Tags: html, linkedin-api

I want to create a website for my company. I want to use my team mates profile pictures in About us page on my website, what will be the best way to get their profile pictures? Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: This question is similar to the following question : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784222/get-linkedin-user-profile-pictures

Comment: @mbejda I looked into it, but I was unable to comprehend it : /

Comment: Tried to improved OP's question, but its better if he/she add something more..

Comment: This question will likely be closed for lack of effort on the part of the asker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take look at this. [Linked-In Api](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields)

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/{user-id}/picture-url
```