# Linkedin profile photos from profile URL

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to pull image of linkedin profiles. I have profile urls in an array. Is it possible to extract user id from linkedin profile urls and use following api to get image of profile without authenticating user.

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/{user-id}/picture-url
```

Comment: It's illegal :) it's called scraping, and you must first pass through oAuth

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting LinkedIn Profile Picture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955647/getting-linkedin-profile-picture)

Comment: @MarkoMackic i dont want to scrap. I can pass through oAuth but is there a way that I get access token for my account and then i dont have to ask user to give permission to their photos.

Comment: you'd probably want to see linkedin api (not sure they have it)

Comment: @MarkoMackic i could not find in API but a friend said he does it somehow. Thats why asking here.

Comment: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2

Comment: @MarkoMackic i saw that link already. According to that link user will have to give permission. i have a database of linked in profile urls and i want my friends to search on a page and then show profile images of those urls. I can do same thing with facebook urls.

Comment: @MarkoMackic, not sure calling it "illegal" is technically accurate. Google, after all, scrapes millions of webpages, as does the Wayback Machine. Be careful using words which are so clearly defined when talking about situations you may not have completely researched.

Comment: Ok :) I agree :)