# How to get LinkedIn profile picture using access_token

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm using v2 me api of linked in as per the doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/profile-picture)

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id, firstName , lastName ,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))

This access token is obtained with r_liteprofile.

Still I'm not getting any information related to profile picture (only id, firstName , lastName are coming in response)

Similar Question : [Getting LinkedIn Profile Picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955647/getting-linkedin-profile-picture/53886138#53886138)

Is there any other way?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: This is resolved. It seems, When Image not present on a profile, Response will not contain the object.